# Не пойму как записывается Cache в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Допустим у меня `cache` записывается в файл:

```
if (Auth::check()) {
    Cache::store('file')->put('userIsOnline-' . Auth::user()->id, 'true', now()->addMinutes(1));
}
```

В самом файле кеша я вижу такую запись:

```
1553595759s:4:"true";
```

Так вот, суть моего не понимания:

1) `1553595759s` - Время истечения кеша, но после того как истекает  время его существования, я обращаюсь по ключу к нему, то мне всё равно выдаётся это значение. Т.е. Мне нужно самому сравнивать время и из этого делать вывод истёк кеш или нет?

2) `4` - что это такое? Во всех файлах кеша это число есть....

3) `"true"` - где хранится ключ (`userIsOnline-{id}`)? Почему в кеше только значение?

p.s. Laravel 5.7

Comment: Не до конца понятен вопрос. Вы пытаетесь понять механизм работы кеша в laravel или не понимаете, как получить из кеша значение по ключу?

Comment: @Alexxosipov, Интересует ответ на три вопроса которые под циферками 1,2,3

Comment: Имя файла кеша это хеш ключа. Возможно у вас рассинхрон по времени где то.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Весь функционал файлового хранилища кеша Laravel находится здесь: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php

Если вы сохраняете в кеше какое-то значение со сроком хранения 1 минута, то после истечения 1 минуты попытка получить это значение из кеша

```
Cache::store('file')->get('userIsOnline-' . Auth::user()->id);
```

Должна закончиться получением `null`. Самому никаких дополнительных действий производить не нужно. Если вы все же получаете какое-то значение, то, скорее всего, у вас все-таки где-то перед вызовом `get(...)` вызывается `put(...)` с интервалом меньше, чем 1 минута.

Ключ в файловом кеше нигде не хранится, при сохранении в кеш ключ сразу хешируется `sha1`и разбивается на несколько частей, из которых складывается путь к файлу, в который будут записаны данные. Подробнее смотрите метод [path()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php#L213).

В сам файл данные [записываются](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Cache/FileStore.php#L65) в таком виде:

```
1553595759s:4:"true";
```

Где `1553595759`(10 цифр) - Timestamp окончания времени хранения, а  `s:4:"true";` - сериализованные данные, хранящиеся в кеше (в вашем случае - результат `serialize('true');`).

Comment: Спасибо огромное за столь развёрнутый ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Это результат работы функции [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php)
4 - это количество символов в строке `"true"`